# how to reduce the loss and loss val of my model which do not show any improvement?

Tags: conv-neural-network

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv1D,BatchNormalization
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LeakyReLU
from tensorflow.keras.layers import MaxPool1D,Dense,Dropout,Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.layers import MaxPool1D,GlobalAveragePooling1D
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.backend import clear_session
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from sklearn.model_selection import GroupKFold,LeaveOneGroupOut
from scipy  import stats
#from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
gkf=GroupKFold()
import gc

def cnn_EEG_model_version_2():

    
    clear_session()
    model=Sequential()
    #conv 1
    model.add(Conv1D(filters=4,kernel_size=16,strides=1, activation = 'relu',input_shape=(250,19)))#1
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    #model.add(MaxPool1D(pool_size=2,strides=2))#2
     #conv 2
    model.add(Conv1D(filters=8, kernel_size=16,strides=1,activation = 'relu'))#3
    #model.add(MaxPool1D(pool_size=2,strides=2))#4
    #conv 3
    model.add(Conv1D(filters=8,kernel_size=8,strides=1,activation = 'relu'))#7
    #model.add(MaxPool1D(pool_size=2,strides=2))#8
     #conv 4
    model.add(Conv1D(filters=16,kernel_size=8,strides=1,activation = 'relu'))#7
    model.add(Conv1D(filters=16,kernel_size=4,strides=1,activation = 'relu'))
    #model.add(LeakyReLU())
    #model.add(MaxPool1D(pool_size=2,strides=2))#8
    #fully connect layers
    model.add(GlobalAveragePooling1D())
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(units=10,activation = 'relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(units=5,activation = 'relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'))#11
  
    #model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate =.01),loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

model=cnn_EEG_model_version_2()
model.summary()



accuracy=[]
History = []

for train_index, val_index in gkf.split(full_train_set, full_labels, groups=full_group_array):
    train_features,train_labels=full_train_set[train_index],full_labels[train_index]
    val_features,val_labels=full_train_set[val_index],full_labels[val_index]
    #scaler=StandardScaler()
    train_features = stats.zscore(train_features.reshape(-1, train_features.shape[-1]), axis = None ).reshape(train_features.shape)
    val_features = stats.zscore(val_features.reshape(-1, val_features.shape[-1]), axis = None).reshape(val_features.shape)
    #train_features = scaler.fit_transform(train_features.reshape(-1, train_features.shape[-1])).reshape(train_features.shape)
    #val_features = scaler.transform(val_features.reshape(-1, val_features.shape[-1])).reshape(val_features.shape)
    model= cnn_EEG_model_version_2()
    History = model.fit(train_features,train_labels,epochs=50,batch_size=32,validation_data=(val_features,val_labels))
    accuracy.append(model.evaluate(val_features,val_labels)[1])
    del train_features,val_features
    gc.collect()
```

[image]

I [image] am creating a CNN model to classify EEG data to two class 0 and 1.
after i have trained the model several time with several changes. I noticed that the loss and loss_val doesn't improve at all and doesn't go less than this. I couldn't identify what is the problem with my model.

Comment: It would be really hard to debug this without the data. Check your labels and make sure they're what you expect.